# Is there a way to automatically synchronise the Speed Dial Firefox add-on at browser start-up?

Tags: linux, sync, firefox-extensions, firefox-sync, speed-dial

I am an avid user of the [Speed Dial](http://speeddial.uworks.net/) add-on for the [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) browser. I use it on a number of GNU/Linux systems which all have access to a GNU/Linux file server.

Here is my question:
Is there a way to automatically synchronise the Speed Dial Firefox add-on at browser start-up against a dials list stored on my file server?

If only I would know where the Speed Dial extension stores its information locally, I think a solution using a bash script and a distributive revision control system like [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) would be feasible.